# What is the Best Way to Learn About Bitcoin?

Tags: introducing-bitcoin

I Want to know what is the best way to learn about bitcoin?

Comment: https://www.coindesk.com/information/

Answer (score 0):

The way I learnt was to purchase the book Mastering bitcoin by Andreas Antonopoulos and studied each page and did any practical work that was in the book. I also read the same authors internet of money series of books. [Andreas Antonopoulus books](https://antonopoulos.com/books/). I also took the Princeton course on bitcoin and completed all coursework and exercises [Princeton Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/cryptocurrency). I next went through the documentation on bitcoin.org and and did the tutorials on that site.